# Play Embedded Facebook Video on Click

Tags: jquery, wordpress, facebook, video

I have a website and I am using "Facebook Video Gallery"  to show my Facebook videos. I want to play the video when I click a button. The Facebook video is added using an iFrame. Is there anyway to do this?

The main thing that I need is to add a play button over the video because it doesn't have one at the moment. Right now I have it set up with a div containing a play button over the video. When I click it the play button , it disappears but I would also like the video to start playing.

I am open to other suggestions as well but would like the videos to automatically get added to the website so I don't have to embed them each time.